# Ant copy classpath jars to a directory

Tags: java, ant, copy, classpath

I'm sure this has either been asked before or is pretty straightforward. But for whatever reason, I cannot seem to make it work. I want to use ant to copy the `${build.classpath}` (which contains a colon separated list of jars) to the `${output.dir}/myapp/WEB-INF/lib`.

I have this right now and it doesn't seem to work:

```
<copy toDir="${output.dir}/myapp/WEB-INF/lib">
  <fileset file="${build.classpath}" />
</copy>
```

It treats the whole classpath as one file. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Ant Manual on the copy task contains the answer for your problem. One of the example snippets it provides:

> Collect all items from the current CLASSPATH setting into a destination directory, flattening the directory structure.

```
<copy todir="dest" flatten="true">
  <path>
    <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
  </path>
</copy>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I must've overlooked this somehow. This worked perfectly. It copies everything in the `classpath` to the destination directory. But the `classpath` may contain directories or files that are not jars, how do I exclude anything that is NOT a jar file?

Comment: Replace the path usage with <path refid="java.class.path"/>.

Comment: The must important part of the answer is the **`flatten="true"`** option. If you don't set, I will do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I think somethink like this should work:

```
<copy todir="${output.dir}/myapp/WEB-INF/lib" verbose="yes" flatten="yes" failonerror="no">    
   <fileset dir="${build.classpath}">    
      <include name="*.jar" />    
   </fileset>    
</copy>
```

or with wildcard in include: `<include name="**/*.jar" />`

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work at all. The `classpath` contains colon separated list of paths. The only thing that worked for me so far, is `user268396`'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put all your colon separated jar files to one root folder. If it is not possible then create a separate task that put those jar files into one folder(may be temporary). And assign  `${build.classpath}` to that folder. Use `<fileset dir="${build.classpath}"/>` in your copy clause.

I hope, it should help.